# Autoload function not working in php to get classes from subfolder

Tags: php, oop

In my script autoload function is not working when i did with simple include_once then it's worked. but when i include with autoload i got fatal error for didn't find file. please check my code and tell me where i am wrong.

This is working without autoload:-

```
      <?php

    include_once "classes/Logger.php";
        include_once "classes/userprofile.php";


     $loginmessages = new checklogin();

    echo $loginmessages->createuser();

     ?>
```

But i want to get classes with autoload but it didn't work this is autolaod function:-

```
       <?php

        function __autoload($class){
          include_once "classes/$class.php";
           }


       $loginmessages = new checklogin();

        echo $loginmessages->createuser();

             ?>
```

Please check and tell me how to fix that. thak you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The autoload function is loading "classes/checklogin.php". The $class variable is the same as the name of the class, so you either have to change the name of the file,change the name of the class or do some logic in autoload function.

Comment: How will you please overright my code to systematic my issue ??